# Set data in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I try use UITableViewCell. My custom cell has  StackView's and other views.
I need to send object from controller (UITableViewController) for next parsing it.
 in cell I set field:

```
  class MyCell: UITableViewCell {

    var myObject : MyObject?



    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {

        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

      in this I try get data from my object 



    }



}


    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {

        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")

    }



    override func awakeFromNib() {

        super.awakeFromNib()

        // Initialization code

    }


}
```

and in my Controller I write:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        // create a new cell if needed or reuse an old one
        let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellReuseIdentifier) as MyCustomCell!

        cell.myObject  = self.arrayMyObjects[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }
```

But everytime I have nil in my cell. Why?

Comment: When and how do you make use of `myObject` in your custom cell class? Show more relevant code from your `MyCustomCell` class.

Comment: @maddy  I get data from my object in init method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your cell `init` is to early to try and access `myObject`. You should use a `didSet` on the property to make the changes when it's assigned a new value.

```
var myObject : MyObject? {
    didSet {
        // Update your subviews here.
    }
}
```